# Delete all images taken with specific camera

Tags: shell-script, shell, find, jpeg, delete

**What I need:**

A command that deletes all `.jpg` files in the current directory and subdirectories that have been taken with a RaspberryPi Camera.

(Ideally this should work with the Git Bash for Windows, but this would make it just more convenient and is therefore optional.)

**What I tried:**

I already used `find . -name "*.jpg" -size 24k -delete` to delete thumbnails and I found out that the `file` utility is able to display the camera manufacturer (`manufacturer=RaspberryPi`).

**Example:**

```
$ file f49100889.jpg
f49100889.jpg: JPEG image data, Exif standard: [TIFF image data,
big-endian, direntries=10, height=0, manufacturer=RaspberryPi, 
model=RP_OV5647, xresolution=156, yresolution=164, resolutionunit=2, 
datetime=2015:06:09 08:15:03, width=0], baseline, precision 8, 
1920x1080, frames 3
```

**Background:**

The filesystem of an NTFS-Drive got corrupted and I restored the files using testdisk/photorec. Now I've got the files but lost some metadata such as the directory structure and file-names. I restored the most important files from a backup already and would like salvage as much of the remaining data as possible. I need to delete some garbage files to make working with the rest easier.

*Is it possible to combine these commands to achieve my goal? If yes, how? Is there a better way to go about this?*

**Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple way. Below are the contents of a script named `script.sh` in `~/bin/`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
if (file "$1" | grep "RaspberryPi"); then
    echo "rm $1" # <- safety first: just echo, no delete
    # rm "$1" # <- uncomment to delete, leave the quotes
fi
```

Give it permission to execute (`chmod 0750 ~/bin/script.sh`). Then find the files and pass results, one at a time (using `\;`, not `+`) to the script.

```
find ~ -iname *.jpg 2>/dev/null -exec ~/bin/script.sh {} \;
```

Another tool is `identify` from ImageMagick. This tool describes image characteristics and reads image data, including EXIF. It would be much slower than `file`, but there's much more information in the image than the information provided by `file`. It could help when `file` does not describe the data to be found. Its usage might be as follows.

```
identify -verbose "$file" | grep "RaspberryPi"
```

We can test the return code of `grep` (after using `file` or `identify`  in the `if` statement, above) by displaying its return code. From `man grep`:

> Normally the exit status is 0 if a line is selected, 1 if no lines were selected, and 2 if an error occurred.

Combine this information with the knowledge that the `$?` variable contains the return code/value or exit code/value of the very last command executed.

```
file image.jpg | grep "RaspberryPi"
echo $?
```

The lines above would produce a value of zero - match found - for `file` results that contain the string, "RaspberryPi".

```
file image.jpg | grep "Rumpelstiltskin"
echo $?
```

The lines above would produce a value of one - no match - assuming that `file` does not find a match for the string, "Rumpelstiltskin".

Comment: This works flawlessly - I used the method with the script and it works as expected. Thank you very much!